# how to solve the error "arg list too long"

Tags: find, ksh, xargs

I am running the commnad `ls -lt *$ID*`  this command is working find if I am running separately but with in the script it returns the below error
`arg list too long`. The id is a unique one there is only one file available with this id. This script is working fine with development environment in production environment only it returns the above error.
So, I have tried with the below command also

```
find . -name "*$TN_ID*" | xargs -L 1
```

this one also working in development environment but not works in production environment.

Comment: What is `$TN_ID`? A directory name or a list of filenames or a file name globbing pattern? What is it that causes the error? Is it  trying to run `ls` with too many arguments, or is it trying to run something that you pass the output of `ls` to?

Comment: I reformat your question to highlight unix part. I would say that `*$TN_ID*` expand to too many filename.

Comment: Unclear: "Does not work" could mean anything. Please clarify.

Comment: The `xargs -L 1` is completely pointless in the question, default command is `/bin/echo` so it takes one argument from stdin, and echoes it; which is what `find` is already doing for you. Besides that I don't believe that the `find` command as shown does not work in your production environment, you must be doing somethings subtely different to what you're showing.

Answer (score 2):

"arg list too long" means in this case that there are too many files matching the pattern. My guess is that the variable TN_ID is not set, making the pattern match all files. Try to add a debug output of $TN_ID before the find command to see whether the variable has the proper value.

Comment: Even matching all files with `find` won't make it generate that error, and neither would `xargs`.

Comment: Yes, as some have noticed, find command isn't used prperly either. If you know there's exactly one file matching the pattern, you don't need find. And if you want to match multiple files using find, you should enclose your pattern in single quotes so it's not expanded by the shell, but passed unmodified to find which will do the filename matching. Please make yourself familiar with these mechanisms before writing production code :-)